# My variable won't increment

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, actionscript, global-variables, increment

My code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var tid:Timer = new Timer(5000);
var rightArrow:Boolean;
var leftArrow:Boolean;
var upArrow:Boolean;
var downArrow:Boolean;
var speed:int = 10;
var score:int = 0



tid.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, flyttRandom);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);


txtScore.text = score.toString();


function flyttRandom (evt:TimerEvent):void
    {
    troll.x = Math.random() * (550 - 0) + 0;
    troll.y = Math.random() * (350 - 0) + 0;
    }
tid.start();
function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
    rightArrow = true;
    }
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) 
    {
    leftArrow = true;
    }
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) 
    {
    upArrow = true;
    }
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) 
    {
    downArrow = true;
    }   
if (meg.hitTestObject(troll) == true)
    {
    score = score+1;
    troll.x = Math.random() * (550 - 0) + 0;
    troll.y = Math.random() * (350 - 0) + 0;
    }   
}
function keyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) 
    {
    rightArrow = false;
    }
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) 
    {
    leftArrow = false;
    }
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) 
    {
    upArrow = false;
    }
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) 
    {
    downArrow = false;
    }
}
function everyFrame(event:Event):void 
{
if (rightArrow) 
    {
    meg.x += speed;
    }
if (leftArrow) 
    {
    meg.x -= speed;
    }
if (upArrow) 
    {
    meg.y -= speed;
    }
if (downArrow) 
    {
    meg.y += speed;
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to create this simple game in flash, where the variable score would increase by 1 every time the object "meg" hits the object "troll", my code runs nice and i get no errors, but I have the problem that the variable doesn't increase when they hit. Seeing as I've tried for some time now with no success and my low skill in flash I am stuck clueless.

Comment: Your troll does move? `meg.hitTestObject(troll) == true` is happening?

Comment: Yes it does move, so the problem lies with the variable somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you interested in seeing the increment in "txtScore"?  It looks like you're setting that TextField once, but never resetting it when score increases.

Try:

```
if (meg.hitTestObject(troll) == true)
{
    score = score+1;
    txtScore.text = score.toString();           // show the new score
    troll.x = Math.random() * (550 - 0) + 0;
    troll.y = Math.random() * (350 - 0) + 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! :) I feel so stupid for not having figured that out already...

Comment: If it worked - accept the answer. That is the rules of Stack Overflow.